# QueryException Exception Error

Tags: jpa, compiler-errors, eclipselink, jpql

### i try to get a List of programme from my table "Programme" with a left join. every thing works fine before, but when i restart my computer this error appears

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services
>   - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException Exception
>   Description: Object comparisons can only be used with
>   OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through
>   query keys or direct attribute level comparisons.  Mapping:
>   [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[idIntervention-->programme.IDINTERVENTION]]
>   Expression: [ Query Key idIntervention    Base entities.Programme]
>   Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Programme jpql="select p from
>   Programme p left join  Intervention i on p.idIntervention
>   =i.PROGRAMME_IDINTERVENTION  where p.operationSuivante <=:d ORDER BY p.operationSuivante ASC")    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.unsupportedMappingForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:1164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.buildObjectJoinExpression(DatabaseMapping.java:271)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:805)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder.normalize(ExpressionBuilder.java:265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1414)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildNormalSelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:549)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1708)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:785)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:716)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:888)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:194)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1583)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)
>     at session.ProgrammeFacade.findByDate(ProgrammeFacade.java:179)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)    at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
>     ... 79 more

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is not the same language as SQL. A join is made on an association between entities. It doesn't require an `ON` clause. And JPQL never usres column names. Always entity and field/prioperty names.

A valid JPQL query (assuming the association exists, but you didn't post the entities) would be something like:

```
select  p from Programme p 
left join p.intervention i
where p.operationSuivante <= :d 
order by p.operationSuivante asc
```

But since you never use `i` anywhere in the query, this join is completely useless.

Comment: thank you for responding to this post but intervention is an other table that i need to be joined to Programme before i get the list

Comment: thank you again i resolve the problem ^^ and sorry for my english